# Is it possible to embed Angular inside Golang application?

Tags: angular, go, assets, embedded-resource

I wonder if it is possible to embed a Angular gui (index.html, javascripts, css, images, etc) into the executable go application.

For example Spring Boot (Java) has the possibility to do this by copying the compiled Angular files into src/main/resources/static folder and these files are then served on the root path (provided one has the spring-boot-starter-web dependency).

Is the new feature of Go 1.16 (February 2021) //go:embed able to do this with an entire folder?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and was possible before Go 1.0 was released—simply via the usage of 3rd-party tooling. For one example, see [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata), [`statik`](https://github.com/rakyll/statik) etc… lots of them, actually.

Comment: As to the last subquestion, the answer is also yes.

Comment: …and while we're on this, using the tag `embedded` was a mistake: it's not what you think ;-) "Embedded" refers to hard- and software solutions working in places where you do not usually "see" them—like, say, running a "smart" lightbulb etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Go 1.16 you can now embed files and directories using the `//go:embed` directive in your source code.

Here is the [package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/) for `embed`.

Here is [a blog post by Carl Johnson](https://blog.carlmjohnson.net/post/2021/how-to-use-go-embed/) that the Go blog referenced upon release of the `embed` package.

Your use case sounds like you could benefit from embedding a directory and using an [`http.FileServer`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer). There's an example of this in the linked blog post. I've also pasted it below.

This example shows how to embed a directory called `static` and serve via HTTP:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    useOS := len(os.Args) > 1 && os.Args[1] == "live"
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(getFileSystem(useOS)))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil)
}

//go:embed static
var embededFiles embed.FS

func getFileSystem(useOS bool) http.FileSystem {
    if useOS {
        log.Print("using live mode")
        return http.FS(os.DirFS("static"))
    }

    log.Print("using embed mode")
    fsys, err := fs.Sub(embededFiles, "static")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return http.FS(fsys)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Micah! That was all what I wanted to know!